# Why does this Swagger Schema validate without error

Tags: swagger-2.0, json-schema-validator

This is my Swagger 2.0 Definition:

```
{
   "swagger" : "2.0",
   "schemes" : [
      "http"
   ],
   "paths" : {
      "/config/batteries" : {
         "get" : {
            "tags" : [
               "Devices / IOs",
               "Energymanagement"
            ],
            "description" : "Battery Settings",
            "responses" : {
               "200" : {
                  "description" : "",
                  "schema" : {
                     "$ref" : "#/definitions/T_batteries"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "definitions" : {
      "NodeMetaData" : {
         "type" : "object",
         "properties" : {
            "valueType" : {
               "$ref" : "#/definitions/ValueType",
               "required" : [
                  "valueType"
               ]
            }
         },
         "required" : [
            "valueType",
            "displayType",
            "displayIndex"
         ],
         "additionalProperties" : false
      },
      "T_batteries" : {
         "type" : "object",
         "properties" : {
            "_BAT_CALIBRATION_meta" : {
               "$ref" : "#/definitions/NodeMetaData",
               
            }
         },
         "required" : ["_BAT_CALIBRATION_meta"],
         "additionalProperties" : false
      }
   }
}
```

This is my Response I am getting from the call /config/batteries:

```
{
  "BAT_CALIBRATION": false,
  "BAT_ENABLED": true,
  "_BAT_CALIBRATION_meta6": {
    "displayType": "Switch",
    "readPermission": {
      "RoleCustomer": true,
      "RoleRemote": true,
      "RoleTechnician": true
    },
    "uiExtension": {
      "dictionaryPrefix": "CONFIG.BATTERIES"
    },
    "valueType": "Boolean",
    "writePermission": {
      "RoleCustomer": true,
      "RoleTechnician": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have cut away most of the actual schema and response just to show the problem.

I have tried this in 2 different tools now and they both say it validates the schema and I have no reason why the call /config/batteries should get parsed against the schema from T_Batteries and there I have written that the field _BAT_CALIBRATION_meta6 is required and the response I get contains it without the 6 in the end.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the schema validation?

ReadyAPI and Json Schema Editor online